# Conda's requirements.txt is not installing properly

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I have a python environment (env_1) with certain libraries installed and create a `requirements.txt` using the following command :

```
conda list --export > requirements.txt
```

The `requirements.txt` file contains the following dependencies in it:

```
beautifulsoup4=4.9.3=pyhb0f4dca_0
numpy=1.15.4=py36h8b7e671_1001
pillow=8.0.0=py36h9a89aac_0
python=3.6.13=hdb3f193_0
sqlite=3.33.0=h62c20be_0
pandas==1.0.1=py36hb3f55d8_0
```

Then I came out of environment using `coda deactivate` and tried creating a new environment(test_env) with the dependencies in `requirements.txt` file using the below command:

```
conda create --name test_env  --file requirements.txt
```

But this reported and error saying :

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- numpy==1.15.4=py36h8b7e671_1001
- pandas==1.0.1=py36hb3f55d8_0

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

software: anaconda

OS :  linux

Answer (score 0):

Try generating the environment's file with:

```
conda env export > environment.yaml
```

More info about conda export [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file).